# How to update defined variable in php?

Tags: php, config

I am learning some `PHP` coding and I am creating a simple `config.php` file.
I that config file I have defined an `API_URL` for my local server for testing.

```
<?php
    DEFINE("API_URL", "http://localhost:8000/api"); 
 ?>
```

I want this `API_URL` to be updated when used to staging server. For example I have this another `php` script that will update the said `API_URL`.

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";

    $API_URL = API_URL;

    // Here I want to update the API_URL in config file to be something like
    // DEFINE("API_URL", "https://mystagingsite.com/api");
    // And I want this new "API_URL" to be updated in config.php file.
    // How will I do that?
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take dynamic variables from `$_SERVER`.
You can use: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

So you can use like this API URL:

```
$api_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/api/';
DEFINE('APIURL',$api_url);
```